# Get related objects on the view

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have related model

```
class Myevent extends Model
{
    public function photo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EventPhoto');
    }
}
```

Ob blade if loop i get items Myevents

```
  @foreach($evetns as $event)
        <b>{{$event->name}}</b> <br>
        {{$event->place}} <br>
        {{$event->description}} <br>
        @foreach($event->photo() as  $item)
            {{$item->id}}
          @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

How can I call related objects in a loop on blade?

Comment: you probably have a type: `evetns` should be `events`

Comment: @KarlHill - please do not fix typos in code, as it could be the cause of a problem

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing correctly, except for one single error `$event->photo` instead of `$event->photo()`

```
@foreach($event->photo as $item)
    {{$item->id}}
@endforeach
```

To clear the confusion regarding brackets https://laraveldaily.com/calling-eloquent-from-blade-6-tips-for-performance/

Comment: @DerekPollard no it doesn't, will throw error, try print_r($model->method())  in your blade, with your own model and relation,

Comment: throws error for me, `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65015808 bytes)`

Comment: With `print_r($model->method())` i got this https://imgur.com/a/A6hNEDt, while with `print_r($model->method())`, i got this https://imgur.com/a/q6q7nFy

Comment: @DerekPollard doubt it.